# How do I convert this MongoDB Date value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

This has me stumped. I am fairly new to noSql, and node.js development. So running into moments of what the heck are pretty common. Yet I cannot come to grips with this one on my own.

We are inserting documents into a mongo user collection and everything is working as it should. What I do not get and would like to have some insight on...is the creation of my users, the _id value is also a date stamp. I can sort on this field and user names corresponds to sign up log entries. Yet for the life of me I cannot determine a way to convert this to a normal time-stamp that is human readable.

520193b4571be99a06000031 is  typical date code.

Here is a collection snip.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("520193b4571be99a06000031"),
  "email" : "this_user@gmail.com",
  "google" : {
    "email" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "expires" : ISODate("2012-10-11T18:30:13.611Z"),
    "accessToken" : "A_Reallly_REALLY_LONG one!!!!####$$$$$$%%%%%%%"
  },
  "login" : "google:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp):

```
ObjectId("520193b4571be99a06000031").getTimestamp()
```

Answer (score 0):

look at here

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

or http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html

and create an objectID and get date from there